# Off-brand laptop batteries?

Tags: hardware, battery

I tend to err on the side of paying too much for quality stuff, but $180 for a standard replacement battery for a Dell laptop makes the $80 knockoffs look pretty tempting.  I wouldn't consider it (batteries really aren't something I want to take a chance on getting a refurb with) - but I was so surprised to learn how popular [off-brand server rails](https://serverfault.com/questions/6063/which-parts-to-skimp-on-when-buying-a-server) are, that I thought I'd fling the question out there and see what stuck.

Comment: If it helps, my experience with off-brand wireless phone batteries is that they are better than the brand name originals- just buy according to spec (Ampere Hours or AH).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got my replacement battery from batteries plus for my laptop.  It's worked as good as the original HP battery when it was new.  In fact according to Linux it's still at 100% the batteries rated capacity and it's about 6 months old now.

It wasn't as cheap as the batteries on ebay but it all came down to if I wasn't happy with it I wanted the option to take it back and deal with a real person.  I also didn't want to wait the couple of weeks it takes an ebay transaction to go through and get the shipment.

Comment: 2 votes for batteriesplus.com

Comment: http://www.batteriesplus.com/manufacturer/48-0/Notebook-Laptop-Batteries.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I bought a off-brand replacement battery for my old/spare Fujitsu laptop in Thailand.  I happened to be over there so I stopped by their "IT Mall" in Bangkok.

I paid something like $50-$80 for it and its been working great for over a year now.

Basically your laptop battery is nothing but a certain number and type of cells put into a plastic case.  There's really not a whole lot of difference between "Dell" and generic provided that the generic cells are reasonable quality.  You're paying for a brand name.

If you're feeling really adventurous you can CAREFULLY take the plastic battery case apart and figure out which cell(s) are bad then simply order replacements (or all brand new ones) and solder them all back up.

I HIGHLY recommend buying the types of cells that already have the soldering tab attached to them as soldering directly onto the end of a battery can be a bit dangerous (ie. heat) if you don't know what you're doing.

But the short answer is... go for it... buy the generic battery.  Most of the time they work just fine.  Avoid the total "bargain basement/too good to be true" deals though.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

When making your decision just remember that Dell don't make those batteries, they buy them in, so in some respects there is no such thing as a genuine Dell battery. $100 is quite a lot of money for a label.

I haven't tried non-"genuine" batteries in Dell laptops but I have tried tried them in several other brands. If it wasn't for the label I would never have been able to tell the difference.

Comment: Good point!  Why did I think they made em themselves?

Answer (score 2):

I have used off-brand batteries for Acer laptop before - in fact they were purchased via ebay from some outfit in China, and they charged me half price because it was a prototype.

The comfort of using PayPal and being able to put the transaction into dispute if the goods are not up to spec.

Comment: But were you happy with the battery you bought?

Comment: Yes - it work a treat, exact fit, seemed to have similar capaity to the original and is still in use 12+ months later...

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [intelligentbatteries.com](http://intelligentbatteries.com).

Not only are they the cheapest online source I've found, they're also dependable and make good batteries (they buy the old casings and electronics and put new LiIon cells in them). I've already bought 4 replacement batteries from them.

The only place cheaper I've found yet appears to be very shady and has lots of negative reviews online.

Comment: Definitely giving this place a look, as well.  Thanks!

Comment: They don't seem to have batteries for newer Thinkpads (yet), but great prices on batteries for other systems.

Answer (score 2):

I used to know a guy that refurbished his own laptop batteries. He would open the battery up, take one of the cells down to Radioshack, and buy however many were actually bad. He said most times it was just the first few that were dead. I only ever tried this myself once, and couldn't get replacement cells because the battery I opened was from a very small-name laptop manufacturer that has since gone bankrupt.

Comment: Except that Radioshack doesn't sell LiIon batteries, nevermind ones with solder tabs on them. How long ago was this that you used to know this guy?

Comment: Thought I should try this myself with my dead battery.  With a lot of careful prying, I was able to safely remove the cells and circuitry.  Testing the each cell involves placing a load on it with a resistor, while measuring voltage. See: http://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?t=225973

Comment: Also, came across this rebuild how-to.  YMMV  Laptop models' Li ion cell packaging varies.  But I think this gives a good overview: http://www.electronics-lab.com/articles/Li_Ion_reconstruct/

Comment: It was at least 10 years ago, so they may not have been lithium. If you can source lithium cells, however, the theory should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to consider your warranty status when buying batteries. If you are out of warranty, then no problem - do what you want. But if you are covered by a warranty, then you might have to go with name-brand parts in order to keep coverage.

My laptop (property of my employer) is covered by a service agreement, so when I needed a new battery, IT didn't really have any options but to go back to Dell.

Comment: Simply keep the original battery. If a warranty claim is made just put that one back in. ;)

Comment: There's simply no way that I could possibly keep track of an old, dead laptop battery for any significant length of time. It's simply impossible for me. Your Mileage WILL Vary.

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem in your case, but Sony laptops have a startup program that checks if the battery is genuine and force a shutdown/hibernation if it's not. It's not too hard to kill it, but it's another reason to avoid Vaios.

Comment: Reminds me of the way the old Thinkpads would scream and complain up a storm if you put a non-IBM hard drive in there (do they still?) - amazing how bad they'll make themselves look.

Comment: @Kara: Actually, that was because the IBM harddrives had some special features (notably fast head parking for the Automatic Protection System) which other drives did not hav. Thus you'd get a warning that these features were not supported; the drive would still work.

Comment: Oh sure, they worked!  Scared the bejeezus out of new users booting it up for the first time (which was kind of worth it, doncha think?)

Answer (score 1):

The company I work for uses a lot of laptops, and as such goes through a lot of batteries.  I investigated both aftermarket and OEM batteries, and every single OEM battery had a higher rating than its aftermarket counterpart.  If you need the most performance possible on a single charge, opt for the OEM.  If you're fine with slightly lower performance and don't mind swapping out/charging sooner, then aftermarket will be fine.  I purchase OEM batteries on our more current laptops, and aftermarket on our older ones.